# Kaa: How to configure the IP address and port

Tags: kaa

I have couple of questions
I am new to Kaa and evaluating the product. I was testing the demo applications and went through the steps of the Data collection demo. I tested it and it was working fine but when I again tested the next day it's not working I think this could be because the sandbox  IP address changed.

I was also wondering where to configure the server ports onto which the endpoints connect.

Answer (score 0):

By design, the Kaa operations service IP address and port is embedded into the Kaa SDK during its generation process. This is done for support of cluster Kaa configuration and to simplify the management process.

On the other hand, this means you should download a new SDK and re-build your application (with that SDK) each time the Kaa IP address changed. Which also means that you should manage to make your network preserve the Kaa IP address static.

There is no option (at least for now) to change the Kaa IP address and/or port without re-generation of the SDK.